# Formula for relative homotopy groups of products

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, geometry, algebraic-topology, product-space

In Hatcher prop 4.2 he proves that the n-th homotopy group of a product $X\times Y$ (for $X$ and $Y$ path-connected) is isomorphic to the product of the n-th homotopy groups of $X$ and $Y$. I wonder if a similar statement is true for relative homotopy groups? I.e. do we have a statement like 
$\pi_n(X\times Y, A\times B, (x_0,y_0))=\pi_n(X,A,x_0)\times \pi_n(Y,B,y_0)$?

Comment: I don't believe it holds like you have stated. Note that the product of pairs looks like $(X,A)\times (Y,B)=(X\times Y,X\times B\cup A\times Y)$, and I believe that it does hold that $\pi_n(X,A)\times \pi_n(Y,B)\cong \pi_n((X,A)\times (Y,B))$.

Comment: @Tyrone Your final formula is certainly correct: as you say it is just the universal property. And here is an example that shows OP's formula isn't right: take $A = X$ and $B = \varnothing$. (If this feels too trivial take $B = *$.)

Comment: @MikeMiller $B = \emptyset$ is impossible since $y_0 \in B$.

Comment: @PaulFrost Good point, silly mistake. In any case, $B = y_0$ still presents a counterexample in most cases, the easiest being $X = Y = S^1$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Please check my answer, I hope I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: @Tyrone I guess you are right. However the OP does not consider $(X,A) \times (Y,B)$, but $(X \times Y, A \times B)$.

Comment: @PaulFrost I think my comments were mistaken: the product in the category of pairs (triples) is simply the termwise product, as you say in your answer. I apologize for the misleading comment. Further, my supposed counterexample was wrong ($\pi_2(S^1 \times S^1, S^1 \times *) = 0$, but I mistakenly identified it with $\pi_2(S^1 \times S^1/(S^1 \times *)) = \pi_2(S^1 \vee S^2) = \Bbb Z[t, t^{-1}]$; of course relative homotopy groups and homotopy groups of quotients are not the same.)

Comment: @Tyrone The question is based on the categorical productof $(X,A,x_0)$ and $(Y,B,y_0)$ in the category of pointed pairs which is **not** $(X \times  Y, X \times B \cup A \times Y)$. The latter occurs for example in the relative version of the Künneth formula and in the exponential law for pairs. It may be regarded as a "topological version" of the tensor product for modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\pi_n(Y,B,b_0)$ is the set of homotopy classes of maps $(D^n,S^{n-1},*) \to (Y,B,b_0)$. Hatcher's proof of 4.2 applies verbatim to relative homotopy groups: Maps $(D^n,S^{n-1},*) \to (X_ 1\times X_2, A_1 \times A_2, (a_1,a_2))$ can be identified with pairs of maps $(D^n,S^{n-1},*) \to (X_ i, A_i,a_i)$, and the same is true for homotopies.

Comment: So you are saying the formula I stated is true? I‘m confused because of the counterexample of the comments.

Comment: Yes, it is true. The comments were based on a definition of $(X,A) \times (Y,B)$ which does not agree with that in your question.

Comment: @usee454042 I was just wrong.